# How do I gather multiple jQuery objects into one jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have these variables:

```
var container = $("div#my-awesome-section");
var foo_input = $("input[name=foo]", container);
var bar_input = $("input[name=bar]", container);
```

I want to bind an event handler to both inputs. I hoped this would work:

```
$([foo_input, bar_input]).on("keypress", function() { /* ... */ });
```

But alas, no. Is there a convenient way of gathering multiple jQuery objects into one for purposes like this?

Answer (score 4):

use in **[add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)** in jquery for `adding jquery object`

```
foo_input.add(bar_input).on("keypress", function() { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

for using with object, you need to use **[.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)**

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```
 foo_input.add(bar_input).on("keypress", function() { /* ... */ });
```

**Solution 2:**

also you can simply use comma separated multiple selector:

```
 $("input[name=foo],input[name=bar]", container).on("keypress", function() { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: I have bound the jQuery objects to variables so I won't have to repeat the selectors elsewhere. Having to repeat the selectors every time I bind an event handler would defeat that purpose.

Comment: you are looking for `.add()`. see the first part.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$.each([foo_input, bar_input], function() {
    /* ... */
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqvpuswo/).

In your case use:

```
$.each([foo_input, bar_input], function() {
    $(this).on("keypress", function() {
        /* ... */
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs for [jQuery's `add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function, I noticed that my original attempt was *almost* correct. It is possible to initialize a jQuery object with an array of DOM Elements, so I could do this:

```
$([foo_input[0], bar_input[0]]).on("keypress", ...
```

I highly prefer the `add()` function though.